# what is the largest open set contained in {${x|f(x)=g(x)} $}?

Tags: real-analysis

Consider $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = {x}^{1/3}$. let g(x) = $\sum_{n=0}^{∞} a_n(x − 3/2)^n$  where $a_n=  \frac {{f}^{(n)}(3/2)}{n!}$ for $n≥0$. what is the largest open set contained in  {${x|f(x)=g(x)} $}?

my answer : i think largest open set will be $(-3/2,0) \cup (0,3/2)$   ...

is its correct or not ? pliz tell me

or give me any hints or if u have time pliz tell me the solution  i would be more thankful..

Comment: Hi! I fixed a couple of things in the MathJax structure. It would be really great if you on your side you could fix the English, this is not a text message that you're writing - thanks a million!

Comment: can u tell me the only answer @Arnaud Mortier ,,as i will thinks about this problem

Comment: You need to compute the radius of convergence of your series. The answer will be centered around $3/2$ rather than $0$.

Comment: that mean (3/2,∞) is it correct @ Arnaud Mortier

Comment: pliz reply,,me @ArnaudMortier

Comment: $(3/2,\infty)$ **isn't** correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complex analysis fact: power series converge up to the nearest singularity of the function. In the case of your series, we have a singularity at $x = 0$ and the radius of convergence will be $3/2$...

Alternatively, you can calculate explicitly the coefficients of the series, check the radius of convergence and prove that converges to $f$ applying Taylor.

Comment: First of all.. i would like to thanks u for replying my answer ,,now pliz tell me.... that  answer will be |x| ≤3/2  is it corrects? @ MARtin-BLas Perez Pinilla

Comment: @Michael, the answer is $(3/2 - 3/2,3/2 + 3/2) = (0,3)$ (center $= 3/2$, radius $= 3/2$).

Comment: thanks u so muchs  @ Martin _Blas Perez Pinilla